# How to delete session in Laravel 5.3 without using Request?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a method in a controller that needs to handle the session. That method is called by a get method that doesn't require any user input, so I would like to do it without `Request` class.

Currently, I am able to set the session, but I cannot find a way to delete it. It looks something like this:

```
if ($boolean_storing_condition_value)
    session(['some_data'=>'Some Data']);
else
   /* What should be the unset function? */
```

In Laravel 4.2, it is done with `Session::forget('some_data');` or `Session::flush()`. How should that be done in Laravel 5.3?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [the session helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-session) without having to use a request object.

```
session()->forget('some_data');
session()->flush();
```

Comment: It works, but too bad that it doesn't say that the flush and forget is also included in the helper function. I thought the beginning `$request->` is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.3 you still can use `flush()` and `forget()` methods:

```
session()->flush();
session()->forget('key');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#deleting-data

Answer (score 4):

add `session()->save();` after that.

Comment: Thank you! This was the missing part for me! I am using Laravel 5.7.26

Answer (score 2):

To delete session variable in Laravel 5.6

```
session()->forget(['key1']);
```

to delete the session variables (More the one value delete from the session) use  the arguments as arguments **session()->forget([' ']);**

```
session()->forget(['key1','key1','key3','...']);
```

Comment: Please explain in detail your code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!